# Pgfplots Boxplots with a thick line at the mean value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, best-practices, r, boxplot

[`pgfplot`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) produces nice looking plots, that have consistent look and feel. But sometimes you have a good reason to change that look, and I found it tricky to change style of an specific line, circle, etc.

I am using R to process my data, and I need to create a [boxplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) and use it with LaTeX. Using tikz/pgfplots to draw boxplot, I can produce the boxplot using data generated by R, but I want boxplots that have **thick line in the mean value**. Using keyword thick causes all lines of the boxplot to be drawn thick.

This is an [example from pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) that I use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary[statistics]
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y]
\addplot+[
boxplot prepared={
    lower whisker=5,
    lower quartile=7,
    median=8.5,
    upper quartile=9.5,
    upper whisker=10,
},
]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\ 1\\ 3\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My desired plot should look like this:

[image: tikz pgf plot]

which is created with R, and it should optionally have a dashed vertical line, and smaller min and max limits.

Comment: The line in the box represents the median, not the mean. Are you asking how to represent the mean with a line, or do you just want to change the style of the median line (in that case, simply put `every median/.style=very thick` in the `boxplot prepared` options).